# Save query result into specific column

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

This might seem like a noob question, but here's the thing:

[image: Here's my two tables]

In the image, the first table name is facturaDetalle and the second one's facturamaster

I want to SUM all the total matching ***idfactura*** in **facturadetalle** and save them into the ***total*** column in the **facturamaster** table.

[image: Something like this]

I'm working on a master-detail form in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE m
SET total = (SELECT SUM(d.total) FROM dbo.facturadetalle d WHERE d.idfactura  = m.idfactura)
FROM dbo.facturamaster m
--WHERE m.total IS NULL
```

Comment: This one worked! Now I want it to update every time I add a new detail, how would I do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UPDATE` statement to do that.

```
UPDATE m
SET TOTAL = SUM(d.Total)
FROM  idfactura AS m
INNER JOIN idfacturaldetelle AS d
ON m.idfactura = d.idfactura
```

Comment: I'm getting an error " the multi-part identifier "m.total" could not be bound. Sorry, I'm new into this.

Comment: This is the right approach but your syntax is off slightly. I edited your answer so the syntax is correct.

Comment: thanks. I was typing fast. I should have tested it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.